# Graph data which is only generated once a day or a week?

Tags: munin, graph

I'm wondering what would be a smart solution to graph a data which is generated once a day or once a week.

More specifically, I'd like to graph e.g. how long the last Solr optimization has run, how many digest emails I generated from my application, how many invalid database records where purged during the weekly run, etc.. Things which definitely only happen once in a while.

- Should I pretend that the value (e.g. how long did the Solr update take?) is valid until the next time it is generated? A GAUGE where I read the value from a file which just gets updated once in a time? This graph then will consist of  a line which changes when a new value arrives?
- Should I only record it when it happens and then forget the current value? A COUNTER? This graph then will only have green spikes when a new value has been generated.

Any other ideas? Or *right tool, wrong job*?

**Update**

I probably should mention that I've already running munin in large, but every data gathered so far is the usual munin-data-chages-every-five-minutes idiom; that's why I seeking an advice how to could be handled smart with munin.

**Update 2**

I now solved it with a simple GAUGE which I reset after I handed the value over to munin; graphs look ok to me. There's a [ABSOLUTE type](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/wiki/fieldname.type) too, which reads "... *Another usage is for things you count like number of messages since the last update.* ...". However the graph simply didn't work, it showed no data and always was "NaN". As I had no working example I simply scratched this effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRDtool, which munin uses behind the scenes, can be used perfectly well for this purpose; although it's usually used for frequently updated data, it works just as well if you tell it that it'll only be getting data points once a day or once a week.  However, munin isn't flexible enough to take advantage of this feature of RRDtool (as per http://munin.projects.linpro.no/ticket/5), so you're either stuck with doing it by hand (seriously, rrdtool is *easy* to use) or finding a data collection and graphing that isn't so dodgy.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that I'm already using munin; I wouldn't want to use RRDtool separately I think.

Comment: Canoe paddled.  Enjoy.

Comment: I guess, yes, I will just write the seldom generated data into some dedicated storage and just read this value permanently with munin as a GAUGE.

Answer (score -1):

A discontinuous series of values should be graphed without a line connecting them (e.g. a bar graph).

Comment: Just because they're not frequent data points doesn't make them discontinuous.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Perhaps I should have should have said "If a series of values is discontinuous it should be graphed without a line connecting them (e.g. a bar graph)."

Comment: It's still irrelevant to the question asked, since the series of values isn't discontinuous; when you hover over the little downvote arrow it says "This answer is not useful", which is right on the money.